# Plotting variable number of columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have CSV file that has a date column and measurements column. Sometimes there are 4 or more measurement columns. Regardless of the number of columns, I would like to plot all columns on the same plot (same axis, not as subplots). Right now I have the following syntax for plotting all 4 data - how do I generalize plotting for any number of columns?

```
ax1 = df.plot(x="Date",y=["M1","M2","M3","M4"])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `ax1 = df.plot(x="Date", y=df.columns)`?

Comment: The date column should be deleted so better to use this: `ax1 = df.plot(x="Date", y=df.columns.drop('date'))`